# Model page Template not Activate in Back office Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

my Wordpress has not activate Model Page for template. My plugins are disabled, but that's not the problem.

[image: Screen]

Comment: is it a custom post type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my problem is just one bad space on my comment for template name.

My problem : Template Name : TplName

```
<?php
    /**
    *  Template Name : Book
    */
?>
```

My solution : Template Name: TplName

```
<?php
    /**
    *  Template Name: Book
    */ 
?>
```